# Tell the kernel to SWAP in/out a process by PID

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Basically I have a system with many resident services running, but not all of them at the same time, and very low memory.

Normal solutions of swap just offer "automatic", yet "dumb" swapping behavior based on how often the pages are used. But I know which PIDs are needed at a certain point in time and which ones are not.

What I need is:

- To be able to tell the kernel to swap out specific PID, since I am sure those are NOT going to be used for the time being.
- To be able to tell the kernel that a given swapped PID is needed soon, so it should put back to RAM everything.
- The above 2 to be run in low priority in the background if possible.

The idea is: "I know what I am going to use, so I tell the kernel what to swap and what not to swap. Ideally I would never have any page-fault and I will be able to have more free RAM (by pushing all the unneeded to SWAP)"

I know is possible to lock a PID in RAM using [mlockall()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html). But this is not exactly what I need, it can get a process out of a swapped state, but it can't force it into swap. Also it has to be called inside the process which is not convenient.

I was thinking that if it is not possible with current linux kernels + modules, I could maybe write a small kernel module that hints the swap mechanism, could that be feasible?

Comment: The Linux kernel is over 25 years old. If this feature doesn't exist, I highly doubt it would be considered useful.

Comment: I think it may be useful for my case. Also if it is not possible with the current kernel, is it easy to tweak? Does the kernel have a list of "to_be_swaped_pages" where you can just dump all the pages of a process? Is it possible to set the swapping to a low priority kernel worker?

Comment: The Linux kernel does a pretty good job of scheduling processes, and swapping out the inactive pages of those processes that are not active.  It can't so easily preemptively swap code back in — that might be novel, but I'm not sure you'll actually end up with better performance than using the existing kernel and the default scheduling.

Comment: This doesn't sound hard to add a system call for. The kernel already has the capacity to decide to swap an entire process. Of course you won't be stock kernel anymore.

Comment: I guess this could be (partly) achieved by per cgroup swappiness parameter, see http://serverfault.com/questions/529476/moving-a-process-to-and-from-swap is that what you are looking for? Actually kernel will automatically fetch inactive pages for swapping when time will come, so you could just limit this set to some group of processes, if you have some explicit insight about what will going on in the future.